# Open a link sent in a message using the keyboard

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2010

I try to use my computer while touching the mouse as little as possible, using the keyboard for as many actions that I can.

I'm now using Outlook 2010 on Windows 7. I'm getting a message and there's a link inside it that I'd like to open in my browser. How can I do that with my keyboard, without touching the mouse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to open links in a plain text message with keyboard I found:

1. Open the selected message window with <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
2. Press <kbd>F4</kbd> to open "Find and Replace" dialog.
3. Type "http" (without quotes) into "Find what" box.
4. Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> as many times as needed to highlight the required link's "http" prefix.
5. Press <kbd>ESCAPE</kbd> to close the "Find and Replace" dialog and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to open the link in the browser.

This is actually very fast procedure after 2-3 uses. Please note that next time "Find and Replace" dialog will contain "http" automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move the selection from field to field, and links in the message body of the preview area count as fields it will stop at.  Once it's highlighted hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to activate the URL.

This is a standard keyboard navigation method for Windows. :)

Comment: I pressed Tab many times but the cycle doesn't seem to go through the links in the message. It goes through "From", "To", "Cc", "Subject" and the message contents, but it doesn't stop on URLs.

Comment: Are you sure it actually recognized by Outlook as a link?  If you click the link you're trying to navigate to with the mouse, does it work as expected?

Comment: Yes, when I click it with the mouse it opens in a browser.

Comment: then you'll need to post more info in your question, perhaps some screenshots, type of email it is t(HTML, plain text, RTF?).  Are oyu only having problems with this specific email, or any/all emails with links in them?  As this is standard navigation, if it's not working then something odd is going on, so we need more info to narrow it down.. ;)

Comment: Are you telling me that when you see a message in your copy of Outlook 2010, and you press Tab after having opened the message, it cycles through stuff and eventually highlights the link?

Comment: Yup, that's what I'm suggesting.  Technically I'm testing on Outlook 2013 (don't have Outlook 2010 on hand), but AFAIK it's been standard for a long time... it's basically how you navigate Windows using the keyboard.  But perhaps there's more separation in 2010 -- if you click the Message body first (to ensure it's activated), does tab act as I suggest?

Comment: Hmm, I now tested this in other emails that have links, and your method indeed worked in them. But in mails sent by JIRA they don't work. The links in there look ordinary, but for some reason tab order skips them. Any idea why?

Comment: Ah, looks like it doesn't work because it's a plain text message. Any idea how to click a link in a plain text message?

Comment: I don't believe so -- plain-text is plain text, so there's no link for it to identify.  I find it odd you could click on it with the mouse to open it. :)